# Difference between two columns of words in natural language

Tags: natural-language, distance-functions

Let's say I have two column of words in natural language (let's assume for simplicity they are of equal length). E.g.:

`["Security", "Luck", "Fullness", "Love", "Order"]
["Calmness", "Uniqueness", "Fullness", "Order", "Love"]`

We can say intuitively that "Calmness" is closer to "Security", than let's say "Luck" to "Uniqueness". Also, we can observe that the positions of "Love" and "Order" are inverted.

So, these two factors should account for quantitative difference between these two column of words.

So, my questions are:

- Is there any ready-to-use quantitative method of comparing two columns of words? It should account for both semantic similarities of individual elements and difference in order of elements.

If there are no such "metrics":

- Is there a way to quantitatively compare semantic similarity between two words?
- How one may combine "semantic similarity" with the "change of position" metrics (e.g. Levenshtein distance) to calculate "aggregate" metric?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to quantitatively compare semantic similarity between
>   two words?

[Word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) are a method that has this aim. There are also extensions that are used to encode whole documents.

> How one may combine "semantic similarity" with the "change of position" metrics (e.g. Levenshtein distance) to calculate "aggregate" metric?

Some people tried using [word embeddings with dynamic time warping](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01666).